# How to enumerate registered states in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to know if there is a way to list all registered states when using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `$state.get()` for the latest version of ui-router, you will notice that passing no arguments to the function should return an array of all configured state objects.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ui.router.state.$state#get
 * @methodOf ui.router.state.$state
 *
 * @description
 * Returns the state configuration object for any state by passing the name
 * as a string. Without any arguments it'll return a array of all configured
 * state objects.
 *
 * @param {string|object} stateOrName The name of the state for which you'd like 
 * to get the original state configuration object for.
 * @returns {object} State configuration object or array of all objects.
 */
```

Comment: How do you do the same thing, but with proper nesting?  IE: I have 5 states, but two of those states each have 3 child states.  But `$state.get()` returns an array of 11 items, instead of an array of 5 items where two items have nested arrays.

Comment: @Suamere take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43658936/2367938