# How to see what states are configured in AngularJS / UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to see all of the states that have been set on `$stateProvider`?

In this case, I would like my state assignments to be distributed across many files. I would like to inspect the built states on `run` or `config` in a different file.

For example:

```
# component1.coffee
angular.module('zoo').config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider.state 'component1',
    url: '/component1'
    template: _template
    controller: 'Component1Ctrl'

# component2.coffee
angular.module('zoo').config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider.state 'component2',
    url: '/component2'
    template: _template
    controller: 'Component2Ctrl'

# componentNavigation.coffee
angular.module('zoo').run ($state) ->
  console.log 'All configured states:', $state.configuredStates # doesn't exist.
```

Is there something that will list out the two states, `component1` and `component2`?

Comment: Duplicate: [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324303/how-to-enumerate-registered-states-in-ui-router)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`$state.get()`

returns an array of all states. Includes the top-level abstract state, but you can filter that out if you want.

[How to enumerate registered states in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324303/how-to-enumerate-registered-states-in-ui-router)

Answer (score 7):

For people who try to get actual URL routes including properly displayed nested states:

```
$state.get().map(function(state) { return $state.href(state.name) })

// => ['/login', '/home', '/something']
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem

```
$stateProvider['stateRegistry'].states['your.previously.defined.router.state'].self;
```