# How to get Angularjs UI Router list of states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to get the list of states configured for the application through Angularjs UI Router? i.e After configuring all the states (aka routes in angular), how to get the array of these states or state objects.

In other words, what is the equivalent of Angular's built in router's "`$route.routes`" in Angular UI Router?

Tried to find in UI Router's api documentation, but can't find it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `$state.get()`.

Following in your controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($state) {
  console.log(angular.toJson($state.get()));
});
```

Would spit out something like

```
[{  
  "name":"",
  "url":"^",
  "views":null,
  "abstract":true
 },{  
  "name":"main",
  "url":"/main",
  "controller":"MainCtrl",
  "templateUrl":"main.html"
}]
```

Comment: Seems like it's been covered here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/21593863/1061668

Comment: It doesn't look like this works, after injecting $state I just get `$state.get() is not a function`